# Split a couple of dates in smaller chunks

Tags: java, date

I have 2 dates:

```
public static Date getStartDate() {
        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020);
        instance.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
        instance.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
        instance.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        instance.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
        return instance.getTime();
    }

    public static Date getEndDate() {
        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020);
        instance.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
        instance.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 11);
        instance.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        instance.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 46);
        return instance.getTime();
    }
```

I have the limitation that if start and end is more than an hour the process will fail, so if i have a big time frame as the previous one i need to split it in smaller chunks not bigger than an hour.

Is there an api that can divide the given start and end time to a list of smaller periods ?

Thanks.

Comment: what you can do is convert total time in to total hours. and add that value to database start timer for one hour for each hour and on timer finish decrease that count-- .

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use for example `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in method, but you can easily write yourself. This constructs a list of `java.time.Instant` objects that are one hour apart, starting from your start date and ending just before your end date:

```
    Instant start = getStartDate().toInstant();
    Instant endExclusive = getEndDate().toInstant();
    ArrayList<Instant> chunks = new ArrayList<>();

    Instant chunkStart = start;
    while (chunkStart.isBefore(endExclusive)) {
        chunks.add(chunkStart);
        chunkStart = chunkStart.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    }
```

Note that the `end` date here is *exclusive*: it's never added to the `chunks` list.

Comment: Spot on! I can see the need of one improvement though: if the `end` is inclusive, the condition should be `!chunkStart.isAfter(end)`. Although, the exclusive/inclusive condition is not mentioned in the question, adding this note in the answer will make the answer more useful for future visitors.